# Angels can't heal in CoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

I've been looking over the books (DtD, DSG, etc.) and I can't find anything that lets them heal others.  The only thing I can find is Resurrection.

Am I missing something?  This seems pretty weird if a DEMON can heal themselves and others (on the mend, Eye for an Eye, Wound Healing) and an Angel can't.

What am I missing??

P.S. Yes, I know about Echos who can use Embeds and Exploits but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Influence and Incepts**

DtD, page 343:

> All emphemeral beings have a degree of Influence over the world ... equal to their Rank

Influence is a little thin in its definition, but an idea of a "healing Influence" is supported; one of the examples of the Strengthen (1st dot) include "make... an animal or plant healthier"

Presumably, this means by at most Rank 4, an Angel of healing could roll Power + Finesse to turn the wounds of mortals (and beyond) back into healthy flesh.

As a "back of an envelope" for such a healing Angel, assuming Power and Finesse at 9 dice each:

=> Spend 1 Willpower per action, roll 18 dice, heal 1 wound

Adding Efficiency Incept (Healing Influence) and Units Incept:

=> Spend 2 Willpower per scene, roll 18 dice, heal 5 wounds

While this requires the Angel's focus and is bested by Werewolves (among others), "heal 5 wounds per action" for the cost of 2 Willpower total is impressive - and Rank 5 Angels would have access to "Mass Create."

---

As user10063 points out, there is a restriction in terms of duration; if healing a wound on a mortal requires influence of 4, the rank of said Angel might have to be pretty high to practically heal a target; again, it comes down to the interpretation of whether healing is intrinsically temporary, and precisely what "Influence: Healing" allows.

And to be a fully complete answer, they do point out that some flavor text implies that (at least some) Angels have healing methods that have no mechanical description.

Comment: It's odd that there is no Numen that would heal in CoD (There is one in WoD).  Looking at how powerful Incepts are, healing would draw attention of local demons and likely other Angels (the Abandoned).  I saw on another forum where another ST allows the "Regeneration" Numina to be used on others.  Would that make sense?  Weird that Demons have so many ways and Angels basically have one.  How would "Create" or "Mass Create" work with healing?

Comment: Regenerate as written, I don't believe allows the wielder to heal beings other than itself. For Influence, I'd personally say: 1  - can alter immune system, 2 - prevent or enhance scarring, 3 - stop or accelerate natural healing, 4 - heal one lethal per success, 5 - heal 1 lethal per success for up to all present or 1 agg total; but again, Influence is thinly described for my taste. DtD does encourage the ST to design Interlocks, though - supplementing the official healing methods would entirely be in line.

Comment: And, as far as the GM giving its servitors so few ways to heal, perhaps it goes like this: first off, the relatively "expensive" Angels can report to repair infrastructure (if they are high enough priority / spare parts availability) but for those squishy little monkeys - if they get hurt enough, just replace them. Unless they are truly important, in which case, slap an Angel or two on them, and maybe think  up a plan B. Or, it thematically fits that the GM is so pervasive because it's "too big to fail" - not because it's particularly efficient. Maybe it just never thinks to build healers.

Comment: For Influence 1 it says "an animal or plant healthier".  Can that be interpreted as healing instead?

Comment: Can it? Sure. Should it? Your call. I'm confident that somewhere in the Werewolf / Mage tracts should be some examples of "healing spirits" - such examples would likely express their intended effectiveness, but I'm not familiar with with either game to dig those out offhand.

Comment: The quote "make... an animal or plant healthier" is completely out of context of the rest of the description. It wasn't talking about removing wounds there. And your first example of Influence usage, with no Incepts applied, wouldn't be spending '1 Willpower,' it would be paying the normal Essence costs. And you're assuming its Rank is high enough for Efficiency to reduce the Essence cost to zero?

Answer (score 3):

Mechanically, there's one really good option in the 2e rules, though it isn't exactly its main purpose: **Possession**. While in a host:

> The entity may pay one Essence per turn to heal a lethal or
>   bashing wound or a point of structure lost to damage.

Now in 1e, there was a Numen, **Heal**, which does what you want. It's in *Book of Spirits*. **Regenerate** also happened to be in the same book, and though Regenerate was imported unmodified into GMC and 2e core, Heal was not. Also unlike Regenerate, Heal could remove *aggravated* damage at the cost of only some extra Essence, so it's possible it was left out of 2e for a reason.

> • **Heal:** The spirit can heal others’ wounds, typically for a hefty price. The spirit expends a point of
>   Essence and rolls Power + Finesse. Bashing damage
>   is healed before lethal, and all lethal damage must be
>   healed before aggravated damage. Each success heals a
>   level of bashing damage, while two successes can heal a
>   point of lethal damage. The lethal damage healed can
>   be used to mend aggravated damage, but each point of
>   aggravated damage cured costs one additional point of
>   Essence. (Healing two aggravated wounds calls for four
>   successes and three points of Essence.) This Numen
>   may also be used to help a character fight off disease
>   or the effects of poison — each success adding to the
>   character’s resistance rolls on a one-to-one basis.

On the other hand, **Influences** causing healing seems sort of plausible, but there's a problem. It's extremely unclear how applying e.g Influence: Healing would work in practice, because an Influence is almost always a *temporary* effect, and healing wounds would be a permanent one.

> Influence is measured in both scale and duration. To use
>   an Influence, compare the entity’s Influence rating to the
>   total dots of the intended effect and how long it is to last.
>   The total must be equal to or less than the entity’s Influence
>   rating in order for the Influence to be attempted.

In the description of Influence Effects:

> • Strengthen The entity can enhance its sphere of influence. It can add to the Defense of a loved
>   one, make an emotion stronger, an animal or plant healthier, or an object more
>   robust, gaining the entity’s Rank in Health or Structure.

When it says it can make an animal "healthier," in context it means the same thing as when it says it can make an object "more robust": it strengthens them by making them *temporarily harder to kill*, it doesn't reverse damage. An entity with Influence: Dogs ••• can use Strengthen on a dog, to give it *temporary Health dots* equal to its Rank, raising the dog's maximum health, but only for a limited duration. One with Influence: Cars ••• could give a car temporary extra Structure, which is the equivalent of Health for objects, making it more robust and harder to destroy.

Now a powerful Rank 5 angel might be able to have 5 dots of Influence, which would allow it to use a Strengthen • effect with a Permanent •••• duration. The RAW only suggests this could do things like permanently increase a target's maximum Health, but permanently removing a wound could be argued as an extension of that.

For Influences less overwhelmingly powerful than 5 dots, you'd have to make up a houserule. Maybe **Influence: Healing** could *temporarily* accelerate (you'd have to decide by what factor. Maybe multiply by Rank+1?) the target's natural healing rate, assuming they can heal naturally and aren't undead. But to make the effect last longer than mere minutes, which is useless for anything but healing bashing damage, consult the Influence Durations table:

> •• | One hour per success
>   ••• | One day per success

It would need 3 or 4 dots of Influence: Healing in order to have any practical effect, because for humans lethal damage takes two days to heal. A Rank 3 entity with 3 dots of Influence might, with 6 successes, make the next 6 hours of time count as 24 hours towards healing a single point of damage, and a Rank 4 entity with 4 dots would let a human heal one point of lethal damage every 10 hours or so, for however many days its influence lasts. Alternatively, if you made the acceleration factor "Rank times 10," a Rank 3 entity could reasonably cause lethal wounds to heal in less than 2 hours each.

Incidentally, there is a story told in *Mortal Remains* about an angel healing a permanent injury, effectively a persistent Arm Wrack Condition, of the founder of the demon-hunting conspiracy the Knights of Saint Adrian, but it was done as part of granting their Endowment, Ink.

> The target was
>   an enemy of God. Then he paused,
>   and asked if Casey could track him
>   down. She said sure, but somebody else would have to strangle
>   the guy. And that was when the
>   angel healed her arm, no price
>   attached.
>
> The angel who fixed up Casey Howard’s arm did it by tattooing her in some weird script. It looks a bit arcane, a little
>   high tech. Every so often, he comes by to outfit the new hires
>   with Ink, holy marks that help in the endless hunt for his fallen
>   counterparts.
>
> Casey Howard’s original Ink healed a serious injury. This is the
>   type of thing the Storytelling system doesn’t usually model, so the
>   Ink Endowment doesn’t include an option for a tattoo that heals
>   an individual injury.
>   That said, a character being grievously and permanently
>   wounded is the kind of thing that might happen with a persistent
>   Condition. Optionally, the client might be willing to patch up a
>   seriously hurt hunter. That hunter would have to be pretty valuable
>   to the agency (as represented by two or more status dots) to be
>   worth the client’s time.

Comment: Thanks user10063!!  You say "and was later imported unmodified into 2e core. " about the BoS.  Do you have errata for that? I would love to bring the book into CoD from WoD.

Comment: *Regenerate* was included in 2e, Heal was conspicuously not.